# XML input is not working in ATG 11.1 dyn/admin

Tags: xml, atg

We have created a component to test web service, that component takes xml as input and invoke webservice call.  So we are testing this component through dyn/admin but we put input as XML, it give error as "FORBIDDEN REQUEST", error is generating from XSSParameterValidator.  We tried to disable this component but still it is not enabled.  Can any one know the solution

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do this.

1. The best way for you to do this is by placing the XML payload in a file. And have the component use read from the file and call the web service. This will be very flexible in the long run
2. Create a custom dyn/admin page for your component that can allow you to put XML or any other content so that it escapes the validation
3. Disable the validations like you tried to do. If you want to disable it, remove it from the pipeline by changing the next pipeline servlet so that it does not get called. This is the least preferred option and do not do this in in any production / live environments

Jags

[Object Edge Inc.](http://www.objectedge.com)

Comment: I tried option 2 and 3 still it did not work.  We did not try for the option 1, because it was working in the earlier versions of ATG 10.1 for the option 2

Comment: It is good to understand why it does not work between versions. On option #1, I suggest that you not only disable the pipeline servlet, but also remove it from the chain by changing the next pipeline property of the previous pipeline servlet.